# onclick is working on desktop browsers but no longer working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, vbscript

I have

```
Response.Write "<li><a href='#' onclick=""CloseFormAndReturnValue('" & .strProdNum &"');""><div>"
```

this was working fine for us until today. This works on desktop browsers all of them but not on mobile anymore chrome nor Safari. Anybody have any suggestions maybe change it to a touch even CloseFormAndReturnValue is of course a javascript function.

here is the function code again this all works on desktop browsers just not on mobile

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CloseFormAndReturnValue(strProductNumber) {
        window.opener.document.<%=strReturnForm%>.<%=strReturnField%>.value = strProductNumber;
        self.close();
        return false;
        strReturnForm = Trim(Request("ReturnForm"))   

    }

    function CloseForm() {
        self.close();
        return false;
    }
</script>

<form method='POST' name='frmProductLookup' action="lookup.asp">

<input type="hidden" name="ReturnForm" value="<%=strReturnForm%>">
```

it seems like it does not like the onclick on mobile it just does not do anything.

Comment: If you have a clients side problem, look at the client side code, not the server side code.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 function CloseFormAndReturnValue(strProductNumber) {
  window.opener.document.<%=strReturnForm%>.<%=strReturnField%>.value = strProductNumber;
  self.close();
  return false;
 }
 function CloseForm() {
  self.close();
  return false;
 }
</script>  this is client side code but the function works fine on desktop browsers it grabs the product number and passes it into product number field on the previous page I didn't know if maybe something to do with the onclick because it acts like it clicks on mobile but nothing happens unlike on regular desktop

Comment: `<%=strReturnForm%>` is not client side code.

Comment: You need to create a reproducible test case and edit it into your question.

Comment: I did Response.Write "<li><a href='#' onclick=""javascript:alert('previous')""><div>" and I got my message previous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching the Internet this is a known bug for IOS 8 in safari it is on the line 
Window.opener.document they have yet to release a fix. A work around to this issue is to download Google chrome application and use it because it still works the way it is suppose to on the iphone.